# Huge performance difference: "WHERE x IN (...values...)" vs. "WHERE x IN (<subquery>)"

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I want to query a table `T` for rows identified by some column `x`. The values of `x`, for which the rows should be returned, are determined by some sub-query on table `U`, which carries the actual filter condition on columns `a` (a short string) and `b` (a timestamp value, looking for a range).

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE x IN (
        SELECT x FROM U WHERE a = ? AND b BETWEEN ? AND ?
    )
    ORDER BY x, y
```

Both tables `T` and `U` are quite big (in the range of 1M..100M rows). Their definitions are at the end of the question. In the typical use case, about 500 to 1000 rows are in the result set for about 100 different values for `x`. These values for `x` are *not* consecutive, and indeed very "random".

This query takes quite some long time (in the range of 0.5 to 2 seconds), although proper indices for both tables `T` and `U` are used and indeed only a small number of rows is being "examined" (about 1000) according to the slow query log.

The indices are defined as:

- Index `idx_u` on table `U` covers the columns in the `WHERE` clause (`a`, `b`).
- Index `idx_t` on table `T` covers the columns `x` (to be used to *find* rows) and `y` (to be used for the secondary order criterion).

The `EXPLAIN` for the query above is:

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys  key    key_len  ref   rows  Extra     
1   SIMPLE       U      range  idx_u          idx_u  24       NULL  107   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       T      ref    idx_t          idx_t  8        U.x   4     NULL
```

---

I also tried a `JOIN` instead of sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM T
    JOIN U ON T.x = U.x
    WHERE a = ? AND b BETWEEN ? AND ?
    ORDER BY T.x, T.y
```

The `EXPLAIN` tells exactly the same as above.

---

However, when executing the sub-query separately, and listing the values for `x` literally, both queries together take much less time (in the range of 10 to 20 milliseconds). Also, their `EXPLAIN` looks different.

The first query (originally the sub-query):

```
SELECT x FROM U WHERE a = ? AND b BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Its `EXPLAIN` matches the first entry from above:

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys  key    key_len  ref   rows  Extra     
1   SIMPLE       U      range  idx_u          idx_u  24       NULL  107   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Now the second query:

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE x IN (
        3917,8525,13149,17729,22355,26908,31457,36053,40663,45250 -- ... (64 values here)
    )
    ORDER BY x, y
```

is explained as

```
id  select_type  table  type   possible_keys  key    key_len  ref   rows  Extra     
1   SIMPLE       T      range  idx_t          idx_t  8        U.x   436   Using index condition
```

---

Now I noticed that in the original (composed) query, for table `T`, the guess for the number of rows is only 4, which is way too low. Also, the type for `T` is `ref`, while in the separate query (with explicit values for `x`), it is `range`.

Might the misguessed row number for the lookup in `T` cause the query to be executed in a sub-optimal way? Is the `ref` type the reason for the big performance difference?

And finally, to fix this, can I force `range`? Note that this is not about forcing an index to be used, as it already seems to be used.

---

EDIT: The tables have been created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `U` (
  `x` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `b` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  -- (more columns irrelevant here)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `U`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`x`),
  ADD KEY `idx_u` (`a`,`b`) USING BTREE;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `T` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  -- (more columns irrelevant here)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `T`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `idx_t` (`x`,`y`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: what datatype are the field involve and can you show us the create index?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The involved fields are of integer types (`BIGINT` to be precise). I edited the question and hope that you find relevant information at the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html?

Comment: try creating index for  `(a, b, x)` so doesnt have to look up for `x`, and are you passing the right type to compare with `b` ?

Comment: You say the other columns are irrelevant.  Well, they are not -- since you do `SELECT *`.  If you are selecting `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns it is a big deal.  So, if `*` could be reduced to exclude such columns it _may_ run a _lot_ faster.  Please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

What if you change your query to use `WHERE EXISTS` instead of `IN` operator and since you already tried with `JOIN` conversion

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM U WHERE T.x = U.x
                  AND a = ? 
                  AND b BETWEEN ? AND ?
    )
    ORDER BY x, y;
```

Strange fact is that, I see you have an index on `x,y`(`ADD KEY idx_t (x,y) USING BTREE`) but your explain shows it's performing a filesort `Using where; Using index; Using filesort`

Comment: Hm, never seen something like that. However, I just tried and got a full scan for `T`, which takes very much more time (minutes). The subquery is identified as type "DEPENDENT SUBQUERY" in the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Commenting on your edit: well, the filesort only takes place on `U`, where index `idx_u (a,b)` is used. I don't know what exactly "filesort" means in the EXPLAIN...

Comment: The positioning of "filesort" in `EXPLAIN` is sometimes deceptive; don't trust which line it is on.  Its existence probably indicates that the `ORDER BY` could not (or chose not to) use `INDEX(x,y)`  Please provide the `EXPLAIN`, and be clear what indexes exist when performing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with join like

```
SELECT T.* FROM T
         JOIN U on T.x = U.x
WHERE U.a = ? AND U.b BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY T.x, T.y
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that before, but initially I tried it with a JOIN. Exact same result like the sub-query. :(

Comment: This query must take this much time @leemes

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. JOIN and nested queries both take about 1 or 2 seconds. Two separate queries (subquery + outer query with explicit values for `x`) take 10 to 20 milliseconds *together*.